# Scrollable div with overlay child

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have scrollable div with table inside, and I append loader component as a child to this div. Loader should cover the div when it's scrolled, but it covers only initial size.

Something like this (codepen: https://codepen.io/csscourse/pen/xxyrwOR):

```
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="table"></div>
</div>
```

```
.scrollable {
  max-height: 65vh;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  
  .loader {
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
    .spinner {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background: yellow;
    }
  }
  
  .table {
    background: green;
    width: 3000px;
    height: 500px;
  }
}
```

Blue area is my loader overlay, which I want to be visible on the div when I scroll. Table (green) that is inside the div has dynamic width/height, so I can't make table and the overlay same size. And also, loader overlay has spinner in the middle (yellow block).

How to do this?

Comment: It can't work this way, because the `height: 100%` are referring to the height of `.scrollable`, and that height is just (max) 65vh. You will need to use another wrapper element around the whole thing for this, and then apply `position: relative` to that, instead of to `.scrollable`.

Comment: @CBroe oh yeah, that worked. How simple, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block;` to `.scrollable` so that it takes the `width` & `height` of its content.